# Composition of multivariate functions is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be bounded, $f:A\to\Bbb{R}, f$ bounded and integrable on A.  Suppose $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}, \phi\in C^1(\Bbb{R}), \phi(0)=0$, show that $\phi\circ f$ is bounded and integrable on $A$.

This seems pretty obvious, is it because the fact that $f$ is bounded and $\phi$ continuous so there's extreme values of $\phi$ on $A$, then just use definition of integrability...?

Answer (score 0):

From Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds Theorem 11.2 and Section 13, $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R} $ is (Riemann) integrable iff it is bounded and the set of discontinuities of $f$ in $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ is of measure zero. (We extend $f$ to be zero outside of A, as in textbook.)

Now if $\phi$ continuous then $(\phi \circ f )(A)$ is bounded, as $f(A)$ is bounded, so there is some closed bounded set $B$ with $f(A) \subset B$ and $\phi(B)$ is then bounded. So $\phi \circ f$ is bounded.

Let $D(f)$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$ in $\operatorname{cl}(A)$. $D(f)$ is of measure zero as $f$ integrable. If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then so is $\phi \circ f$. Hence $D(\phi \circ f) \subset D(f)$, and so is also of measure zero. Hence $\phi \circ f$ is integrable.

Comment: Sorry if this requires reading. I remember a proof for the case $n = 1$, where we split the interval into good and bad parts, and bound the good parts with continuity of $\phi$ and show the bad parts are small. Maybe this can be generalized to larger $n$?